# How do I implement the action taken when a specific list item in an Html menu is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css

This is such a basic question but I am having trouble finding the answer - How do I implement the action taken when a list item in an Html menu is clicked?

I’m using an  list in my code as a menu, say:

```
<ul  >
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="level2">
    <li><a href="#">Link 2a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2c</a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
```

I tried giving the menu an id, id="myMenu", and an onclick event, and the js was called, but I couldn’t see a way to identify which item was clicked, just that an line item was clicked in myMenu.

```
<ul id="myMenu" onclick="gothere(id)">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="level2">
    <li><a href="#">Link 2a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2c</a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function gothere(id)
{
alert("got here "+id) ; 
}
</script>
```

I tried adding an id on a child element, id="link1", and that worked, but the js was called for the child and then for the parent.

```
<ul id="myMenu" onclick="gothere(id)">
<li id="link1" onclick="gothere(id)"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="level2">
    <li><a href="#">Link 2a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2c</a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
```

I can use this approach to get what I need but is there a better way?

I am looking for something which sends the least amount of html over the wire (the reason I am redoing this menu from it's former implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't attach the events inline. Attach them with javascript.

```
<ul id="myMenu">
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="level2">
    <li><a href="#">Link 2a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2c</a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>​
```

Note that I'm using jQuery for simplicity here:

```
$("#myMenu").click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rjgd/

With vanilla javascript the concept is the same, use the `target` property of the `event` object to find out where the `click` event originated from.

http://jsfiddle.net/2rjgd/1/ shows how this would be implemented with vanilla js. (in non IE browsers)

```
document.getElementById("myMenu").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
});​
```

Comment: IE uses `attachEvent`. Do a google search for "javascript cross browser event handling" or something similar. There are tons of resources for this readily available.

Comment: Going to bite the bullet and learn jquery. Should have done it long ago.

Comment: @LillLansey It's actually quite simple compared to what it might take to accomplish the same thing with vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the element target or srcElement in your handler, do not pass an argument:

```
document.getElementById("myMenu").onclick=goThere;

function goThere(e){
  e= e || window.event;
  var who=e.target || e.srcElement;
  if(who.tagName=='LI'){
    //handle the clicked list item

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you need a way to identify the element being clicked. Shmiddty gave you method for finding the target of the element that was clicked by name. You could then write an if/then statement to open windows or follow links based on specific names.

That may be more difficult/complicated for you to do than just assigning IDs to the elements and checking them. You can do this in vanilla js, using a statement like this:

```
var myLink1 = document.getElementById("link1");
myLink1.onclick=window.open("http://www.webaddresshere.com","_self");
```

My recommendation is to use JQuery if you can. It lets you do things like this:

```
$('li[id^=link1]').click(window.open("http://www.webaddresshere.com","_self"));
```

Comment: It occurs to me that there may be an even simpler solution than either of these. What are the links on the list items supposed to do?

Comment: The links create a url with parms and branch there

Comment: Ok. My original thought doesn't apply then. You'll either want to use the individual ID method or use Shmiddty's code and identify them individually then do something like:

if (e.target === link1){ //do something here};